# Spring boot container cannot find kafka broker in another container

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, docker-compose, spring-kafka

I have a simple springboot app running in docker container with following configuration.

```
@Configuration
public class ProducerConfiguration {

    private static final String KAFKA_BROKER = "kafka:9092";

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerConfigurations());
    }

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> producerConfigurations() {
        Map<String, Object> configurations = new HashMap<>();

        configurations.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, KAFKA_BROKER);
        configurations.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        configurations.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);

        return configurations;
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
    }

}
```

Controller class

```
@RestController
public class KafkaController {

    private static final Logger LOGGER= LoggerFactory.getLogger(KafkaController.class);

    private KafkaTemplate<String, String> template;

    public KafkaController(KafkaTemplate<String, String> template) {
        this.template = template;
    }

    @GetMapping("/kafka/produce")
    public void produce(@RequestParam String message) {
        template.send("test_topic", message);


    }
}
```

In the same project, following is the docker-compose.yml for kafka

```
version: '2.1'

services:
  app:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: app
    container_name: app

    ports:
      - 8080
    depends_on:
      - kafka
      - zookeeper
    networks:
      - network1

  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    container_name: 'kafka'
    environment:
      JVM_OPTS: -Xmx1g -Xms1g -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: kafka
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT: 9092
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: test_topic:1:1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INSIDE
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INSIDE://kafka:9093,OUTSIDE://0.0.0.0:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INSIDE:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INSIDE://kafka:9093,OUTSIDE://localhost:9092

    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
      - 9093:9093
    networks:
      - network1


  zookeeper:
    container_name: 'zookeeper'
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper

    networks:
      - network1

networks:
  network1:
```

The problem:
When I run the springboot application locally and try to send the message to topic, it works fine.but, when I dockerize the springboot application using `docker build -t my/app` and then `docker run --publish=8080:8080  my/app` and then try to send the message on topic I get the following error

`[Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node -1 (kafka/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.`

I have tried various suggestion around KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME but still its not working.
*Appreciate any help on this*.

EDITS : my dockerfile is

```
FROM maven:3.5.2-jdk-8-alpine AS MAVEN_BUILD
COPY pom.xml /build/
COPY src /build/src/
WORKDIR /build/
RUN mvn package
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=MAVEN_BUILD /build/target/app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /app/
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

Comment: When you run the app in a container it's outside of the network where Kafka is, you need to run it in same network `docker run --network ` when running app, or have app in compose file and it will be assigned same network

Comment: Thanks @Thomas__ for the reply. I tried to updated my docker compose but its not working. I am new to docker so I will need more help. I have updated my question with latest docker-compose and dockerfile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per comment, there are a few things to run your spring boot within same network as Kafka.

Find out what network Kafka is under,

```
docker inspect --format='{{json .NetworkSettings.Networks}}' <kafka_container_id>

response: {"<this_is_network_name>": ...}
```

To get `kafka_container_id` a `docker ps` can be used.

When you know  network name, you can do your run command as currently do with:

```
docker run --network <network_name> --publish=8080:8080  my/app
```

I've noticed you updated your compose file, the networking should be something like:

```
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: my-pre-existing-network
```

But assigning them to an existing network isn't needed, as they are all contained in same compose, so by default they'll all be assigned the same network, so something like:

```
version: '2.1'

services:
  app:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./
    container_name: app

    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
      - kafka
      - zookeeper

  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    container_name: 'kafka'
    environment:
      JVM_OPTS: -Xmx1g -Xms1g -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: kafka
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT: 9092
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: test_topic:1:1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INSIDE
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INSIDE://kafka:9093,OUTSIDE://0.0.0.0:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INSIDE:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INSIDE://kafka:9093,OUTSIDE://localhost:9092

    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
      - 9093:9093

  zookeeper:
    container_name: 'zookeeper'
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
```

Dockerfile should also expose 8080 (assuming you want to hit the spring boot application)

Comment: Thank you so much! that really saved a lot of me. I updated my docker file as suggested  and also updated the broker in my  configuration class something like this  ```private static final String KAFKA_BROKER = "kafka:9093";```